# Changing settings values in an Android ROM

Tags: settings, custom-roms

I have just started to cook my own Android custom ROMs, and I am wondering how I can change the settings values in the "About" screen in the default Settings app.

I have taken Cyanogenmod 7.2 and I am modding it. So how can I change the mod version, for example, from "cyanogenmod 7.2.0 p990" to, for example, "mymod 7.2.0 p990"?

Comment: While not expressly off-topic, I don't think your question will do well here. This site is primarily for _users_ of Android devices. You'll probably do better at a site more geared toward Android modding.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the `ro.build.display.id=` field in the file called **build.prop** within your ROM.

Comment: Thats problably the line i have been looking for, thanks, i'll check it out later today